# What does {A,B} mean in shell?

Tags: shell, brace-expansion

I am reading [this file](https://github.com/flathub/net.codeindustry.MasterPDFEditor/blob/master/net.codeindustry.MasterPDFEditor.yaml), a manifest for a `flatpak` application.

There is the following command:

```
ln -s /app/{extra,bin}/masterpdfeditor5
```

What `{extra,bin}` mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Brace Expansion:
https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html

In your particular example, the shell will expand the brace expansion `/app/{extra,bin}/masterpdfeditor5` to the two strings `/app/extra/masterpdfeditor5` and `/app/bin/masterpdfeditor5` (in this order). The `ln -s` command will receive these two strings as arguments, and as a result it will create a soft link called `/app/bin/masterpdfeditor5` pointing to `/app/extra/masterpdfeditor5`

Comment: Allow me to add that often, people think that wildcards and other expansion syntax is processed by the commands, e.g. by `ln`. It's very important to be aware that it is the shell that processes these characters, not the command. The command gets the result of the shell's processing. There are exceptions; for example, `find` does process wildcards in certain contexts.

Comment: @berndbausch True. In some cases this may stem from experiences with `cmd.exe` in Windows. There the command handles wildcards, quotes and [even word splitting](https://superuser.com/a/328698/432690).

Comment: It's also worth noting that brace expansion is _not_ glob expansion. Brace expansion is [the first to be performed by the shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html), before even variable expansion (which is why you can't put variables in a brace expansion without using `eval`).

Comment: Please note that this kind of brace processing is specific to ksh93 and bash. It is not a shell feature since it is not part of the POSIX standard.